# Comparison of SNARK-friendly hash algorithms MiMC7, Poseidon, Pederson?

Tags: hash, cryptanalysis, homomorphic-encryption, zero-knowledge-proofs, performance

There are some cryptographically secure hash algorithms designed to be efficient for [SNARKs](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/19884/what-are-snarks), [STARKs](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/046.pdf) and [FHE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption#Fully_homomorphic_encryption). Some of them already implemented in [Zcash](https://github.com/zcash/zcash), [Zokrates](https://github.com/Zokrates/ZoKrates) and [circom](https://github.com/iden3/circom). The ones that I know of are:

- [MiMC7 hash](https://iden3-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_downloads/a04267077fb3fdbf2b608e014706e004/Ed-DSA.pdf)
- [Poseidon](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/458.pdf) ([website here](https://www.poseidon-hash.info/))
- [Pederson](https://iden3-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_downloads/4b929e0f96aef77b75bb5cfc0f832151/Pedersen-Hash.pdf)
- [Rescue Prime](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/1143.pdf)

Is there any security and performance comparison available for these hash algorithms? (There have been attacks [published](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/419.pdf) on some other hash functions designed for SNARKs. But, I didn't manage to find a proper comparison for these ones.)

Comment: Don't forget about Rescue-Prime: https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/1143.pdf

Comment: I happen to come across this page: https://github.com/matter-labs/rescue-poseidon this has some sort of performance comparison for Poseidon, Rescue, and Rescue Prime.

Comment: An especially related survey seems to be available here: https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/948.pdf